# Validating a checkListBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two `forms` (1 and 2). I have been battling with some code that would prevent the user from selecting an item in the `checkedListBox` that was not added into `ListBox2` from the previous form (`form1`).

The code I have is kind of weird because even if the item was added to `listbox2` from `form1`, it continues to display the `msgBox`. I need the `msgBox` to display only to those items that were not added to listbox2, form1.

Here is what I have:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ActSubject As Boolean
    Public Function ActivateSubject() As String
        Return ActSubject
    End Function

    Private Sub ListBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.TextChanged
        Dim x As New Items
        x.AvailableItems = ListBox2.Items.ToString
        For Each x In ListBox2.Items
            If ListBox2.Items.Contains(x) Then
               ActSubject = True
            Else
               ActSubject = False
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Dim HaveActSubject As Boolean = Form1.ActivateSubject
    Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedValueChanged
       If HaveActSubject = False Then
            MsgBox("Sorry! Subject should be activated six month before registration.")
       End If
       Return
    End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: why use listbox2_textchanged instead of listbox2_selectedindexchanged ?

Comment: I have no better reason, but either way am not getting the expected output.

Comment: this code basically checks if items in ListBox2 are in ListBox2. You never use the content of the CheckedListBox1 for your validation. Also, ActivateSubject should be a function taking an item as a parameter and checking if that item is in the ListBox2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Function ActivateSubject(itm as string) As String
        Return ListBox2.Items.Contains(itm)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Dim HaveActSubject As Boolean = Form1.ActivateSubject
    Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedValueChanged
       If Form1.ActivateSubject(CheckedListBox1.selectedValue) = False Then
            MsgBox("Sorry! Subject should be activated six month before registration.")
       End If
       Return
    End Sub
 End Class
```